# order_by date_join in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am displaying user information to the admin dashboard I want to order Users by their join date.
and on another page, I want to display only 10 users information which are recently logged in.

I am filtering user data like this:

```
data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(user__is_staff=False))
```

Model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")
def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user} profile'
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have certain fields like last login in Profile to track login history.

Use:

```
user__last_login
```

Now you can filter as:

```
data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(user__is_staff=False)).order_by('-user__last_login')[:10]
```

Comment: After implementing this solution I got an error `FieldError at /admin_home
Cannot resolve keyword 'user.last_login' into field. Choices are: id, image, user, user_id`

Comment: do I have to create the field `last_login`?

Answer (score -1):

**user.last_login**

you can order user queryset based on last_login field and take first 10 using [:10] at end of queryset